# JavaFX: Retain textfield data between scene changes

Tags: javafx

I am currently working with a borderpane as my parent controller. Each time a user clicks a menu option, a new sub section is loaded into the borderpane's center section. One of those sub sections contains a form.

I want a way to persist data that is typed in that form so that it retains when the user returns to the screen so that it doesn't have to be re-entered.

Comment: You can put a VBox into BorderPane's center, and that vbox may include the fixed form, while the replaceable sub section will stay under the form.

Comment: maybe you misunderstood, i dont want the physical form to be retained but instead when i return to that page the data is still populated in the form (if it wasnt submitted)

Comment: Yes misunderstood. What you can is to not throw away the old section. Keep it in memory and show it afterwards when the old section is navigated again.

Comment: keep it in memory how? ive tried making the elements static but that doesnt work (throws an error), are you saying i should create properties for the various controls and make those static and bind them to the controls on the page? i was trying to avoid creating any new variables is there another way?

Comment: Say that form in a layout VBox with fx:id="formPane". Pane formPane = scene.lookup("#formPane"); Now you have the form pane, keep it in a class that lives when navigating from section to section. Thn add that pane to new section's layout.

Comment: good idea ill try to implement that.